# html tag strong and correct way of doing things?

Tags: html, seo, semantics

Take the code below,

```
<strong><a href="#">Link</a></strong>
```

It will make the link bold.

Now consider this next example, does exactly the same thing, but which is the one to use from a SEO and semantic point of view?

```
<a href="#"><strong>Link</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing significant to choose between them.

You should only use these if you want a particular link to have stronger emphasis. If you just want bold links, then you should use `a { font-weight: bold; }` in your stylesheet.

Comment: You can add class or id, for the style on to apply to specific links

Comment: Yes I understand when I should use css and the html tag but surely there are some semantic differences in the two?

Comment: @cgweb87 — Nothing significant.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, wrapping anchors around the text only, or else around the minimum markup required, minimizes browser bugs.

I respectfully disagree with Quentin's comment above. `<strong>` offers true semantic value, while `font-weight: bold;` is by definition a visual semantic descriptor. In support of this assertion, here are links to W3C definitions for both along with the first sentence from each.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#font-weight

  > The 'font-weight' property selects the weight of the font.
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element

  > The `strong` element represents strong importance for its contents.

To get a sense of how deliberate the semantic meanings of elements like `<strong>` are, look at the definition changes for `<b>` and `<strong>` in the W3 documentation for changed elements in HTML5: www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changed-elements